# Class attributes in django templates not being called

Tags: python, django, django-templates

been looking at this for a while now, and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have a view like this

```
def format_guide_datasheet(request):
    return render(request, 'input/format_guide_datasheet.html', {'readers': settings.INSTALLED_DATASHEET_READERS})
```

`settings.INSTALLED_DATASHEET_READERS` is an array of classes:

```
from input.readers import ExcelReader

INSTALLED_DATASHEET_READERS = [ExcelReader]
```

`ExcelReader` class:

```
class ExcelReader(Reader):
    @staticmethod
    def name():
        return 'Excel'
```

The problem is, I can't seem to call any attributes of these classes in my template. For instance, in `input/format_guide_datasheet.html`:

```
{{ readers }}
```

correctly outputs

```
 [<class 'input.readers.ExcelReader'>]
```

whereas

```
{% for reader in readers %}
<li>
{{ reader }}
{{ reader.name }}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

just outputs the `li` tags...

I have tried using both basic attributes, classmethods and staticmethods, but nothing seems to work...

Anybody have a clue what is going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a `name` property of `ExcelReader` class? If what you are actually are trying to call is `__name__` you will get a `TemplateSyntaxError: Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores`

Comment: @Selcuk: Yes, the `name()` is a function of the ExcelReader class. I have tried making this a classmethod as wel as a staticmethod, but neither seem to work. I added the current implementation of the `ExcelReader` class to my question.

Comment: @sthzg: Yes, that was a typo, this is not the case in my real template. I have fixed it in the question, thanks!

Comment: When you say that the `{% for %}` cicle posted here "just outputs the `li` tags..." you mean that neither `{{ reader }}` nor `{{ reader.name }}` are displayed in the template ?

Comment: @help_asap: Yes, exactly. It just seems as if the `reader` variable doesn't exist... I've tried debugging my code as well, and it never seems to enter the body of the `name()` function.

Comment: At least, now we know the _real_ problem: `reader` variable seems not to exist in the template. Focus on that. Exclude one possible cause at time: 1) Maybe it's just a typo elsewhere (in the code you didn't post here). 2) Try use different names for your variables (e.g. `r_list` instead of `readers`, `{% for r in r_list %}`, etc.). If you want to look deeper inside your template, I'd recommend you [django-debug-toolbar](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.3/) Maybe it's an overkill for this case, but it'll surely allow you to see what's going on in your template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the problem, thank you all for your help!

The problem is that when calling a variable that is a class in a django template, django seems to automatically instantiate it (just like it does when calling a function in a template).
The **init** function of `input.readers.ExcelReader` however, had 1 required argument, which meant the django template got an error when instanting an object of this class.

The fix was to make this argument optional. Everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code above and pasted it into a skeleton Django 1.7.3 application and it works.  I get this output:

```
<li>
&lt;input.readers.ExcelReader instance at 0x108a7ecf8&gt;
Excel
</li>
```

The only piece missing from the above code was the Reader class which I declared as an empty class:

```
class Reader:
    pass
```

Perhaps this works differently in a different version of Django or you have some extra configuration or code which is overriding default Django functionality.  Maybe there is another definition of the 'name' attribute somewhere in your application which is overriding the static 'name' method of the ExcelReader class.  Whatever the problem, it cannot be determined from the information posted in the question.